# My Launchpad bug was marked as a duplicate of another unrelated bug. What should I do?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

Some time ago I reported [a bug on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/1299753). Now another user (who is not an active member of the package I filed the bug against) marked this bug as a duplicate to another bug. This is great, as it will prevent my report from expiring but the linked duplicate appears to be only remotely related, and also was marked "invalid". Therefore the duplicate state feels not correct and I commented on that.

Does the duplicate link have any negative effects on resolving the issue? Should I remove the link, or is it better to leave it as it is? What else can be done in such cases?

Comment: It doesn't appear your bug is a dupe & was assigned to a dev prior to being duped. So I set it back for you. (whether it gets fixed or not down the road remains to be seen.

Comment: If this occurs in future - if you feel a bug is improperly duped & have some 'concerns' about who set as a dupe then don't be afraid to set back. If a dev or bug triager marked as dupe then first add a comment like you did & see what shakes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a glance, I'm not sure it's unrelated. And I say that wanting to give you the benefit of the doubt. Your bug does spend some time enumerating a permission problem that is covered by the first comment on the master question:

> These actions were for ConsoleKit. logind has its own rules, so you need to rewrite them to enumerate org.freedesktop.login1.suspend and org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate (see /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy).

The rules have moved. [Here's another bug report that goes over the same ground](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit/+bug/1300460). I know you've seen this before but I want to make sure it's clear, [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit/+bug/1300460/comments/3) is the sort of code you want:

```
# cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/90-mandatory.d/disable-suspend.pkla
[Disable suspend by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend
ResultActive=no

[Disable suspend for all sessions]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=no
```

If that's not enough (either it not working or nor suppressing the menu item, or some mix of the two), edit your bug description and make it super-extra clear that your issue is with the indicator... And then shunt it back to confirmed (or whatever it was before.

In general terms though, you have to look at the bug in question and work out whether or not the master version (or any others linked to it) actually describe or are the source of your problem. If they're not, make that as clear as possible and reopen.